# Add a new field to a layer containing the ovelapping area with another layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, area, overlapping-features

I'm working with QGIS 3.16 Hannover under MacOS 10.13 environment. I've got two polygon layers: `natural_parks` (multiple features) and `region` (single feature). I want to add a new field to the layer `natural_parks` that computes the overlapping area of each Natural Park with my region. Is it possible to do so with the field calculator? So far, I've been able to get it by means of a virtual layer, but I want to insert the results into the original layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can use this expression in field calculator of your natural_parks layer:

```
area(intersection($geometry,collect_geometries(overlay_intersects('region',$geometry))))
```

Explanation: `overlay_intersects()` will get all geometries of the region layer which intersect with your current natural_parks feature and store them in an array. `collect_geometries()` will create a single multipolygon out of this array. `intersection()` will only keep the overlapping part of this multipolygon and your current natural park. `area()` finally calculates the area of this intersection. *So yes, in your case you can simplify the expression since there is only one feature in your regions layer. But I want to keep this answer a little more universal to use.*

Comment: I definitely works but, is there any reasonable explanation for a discrepancy between this calculation and the simple `$area` function? Actually, none of the figures match in those features that fall enterely within the region: e.g. 100637 vs. 100695; 65316 vs. 65340; etc. I know it's not a great deal, but I feel a bit annoyed anyway.

Comment: @JesúsPinilla Yes there is: The area calculated by $area respects both the current project's ellipsoid setting and area unit settings.Calculations using area() are always planimetric in the Spatial Reference System (SRS) of this geometry, and the units of the returned area will match the units for the SRS. This differs from the calculations performed by the $area function, which will perform ellipsoidal calculations based on the project's ellipsoid and area unit settings. (citated from QGIS function help)